# All valid combinations of points, in the most (speed) effective way

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

I know there are quite some questions out there on generating combinations of elements, but I think this one has a certain twist to be worth a new question:

For a pet proejct of mine I've to pre-compute a lot of state to improve the runtime behavior of the application later. One of the steps I struggle with is this:

Given N tuples of two integers (lets call them points from here on, although they aren't in my use case. They roughly are X/Y related, though) I need to compute all valid combinations for a given rule.

The rule might be something like

- "Every point included excludes every other point with the same X coordinate"
- "Every point included excludes every other point with an odd X coordinate"

I hope and expect that this fact leads to an improvement in the selection process, but my math skills are just being resurrected as I type and I'm unable to come up with an elegant algorithm.

- The set of points (N) starts small, but outgrows 64 soon (for the "use long as bitmask" solutions)
- I'm doing this in C#, but solutions in any language should be fine if it explains the underlying idea

Thanks.

---

Update in response to Vlad's answer:

Maybe my idea to generalize the question was a bad one. My rules above were invented on the fly and just placeholders. One realistic rule would look like this:

- "Every point included excludes every other point in the triagle above the chosen point"

By that rule and by choosing (2,1) I'd exclude

- (2,2) - directly above
- (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) - next line
- and so on

So the rules are fixed, not general. They are unfortunately more complex than the X/Y samples I initially gave.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could list all the actual rules you are planning to use.

Answer (score 3):

How about "the x coordinate of every point included is the exact sum of some subset of the y coordinates of the other included points". If you can come up with a fast algorithm for that simply-stated constraint problem then you will become very famous indeed.

My point being that the problem as stated is so vague as to admit NP-complete or NP-hard problems. Constraint optimization problems are *incredibly hard*; if you cannot put extremely tight bounds on the problem then it very rapidly becomes not analyzable by machines in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll rethink about my question again. I tried to strip the details and ask for a generic solution to the problem "Given a set of items, how do I compute all combinations in an efficient way if every pick eliminates a part of the remaining set". Probably that's far too general and I'll try to come up with something better, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For some special rule types your task seems to be simple. For example, for your example rule #1 you need to choose a subset of all possible values of X, and than for each value from the subset assign an arbitrary Y.

For *generic* rules I doubt that it's possible to build an efficient algorithm without any AI.

Comment: Okay, I don't have generic rules (as in: Dear user, please invent more on the fly). Only a couple of so far fixed ones. I'll update the post with a better and realistic example.

Comment: For the rule from the update, the following algorithm can be used. Let's temporary rotate our coordinate system by 45 degrees. (Now our triangles have sides parallel to the axes.) Obviously no 2 points can be on the same vertical line. Moreover, if a point A is to the _left_ of a point B, it must be _higher_ than B. Therefore our rule is to (1) choose arbitrary vertical lines (in old coordinates it would be arbitrary set of parallel diagonal lines); (2) choose a point on each of the lines in descending order. (The values can be arbitrary, just descending order is important.)

Comment: As you see, the algorithm for the simplified rule is already quite complicated. For more complicated rules it would be even more complicated, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the problem is: Given a method `bool property( Point x ) const`, find all points the set for which property() is `true`. Is that reasonable?

The brute-force approach is to run all the points through `property()`, and store the ones which return true. The time complexity of this would be `O( N )` where (a) N is the total number of points, and (b) the `property()` method is `O( 1 )`. I guess you are looking for improvements from `O( N )`. Is that right?

For certain kind of properties, it is possible to improve from `O( N )` provided suitable data structure is used to store the points and suitable pre-computation (e.g. sorting) is done. However, this may not be true for any arbitrary property.